# How to Generate Key Strokes in Tcl

Tags: automation, tcl

I'm working with a certain tool which has a TCL-based shell. I invoke this tool in Linux environment and it opens a TCL shell in which I can execute commands.

In this TCL shell, when I type one or more letters and press tab, it displays a list of available commands starting with the string I already provided.

Now I need to get all the commands available with the tool.
Instead of manually giving one letter in the alphabet and pressing the tab key to get the list, and then copying the shown list of commands to a file,  I'm looking for a way to automatically send a letter followed by a tab key and capture the suggestions into a file.

Any suggestion on how can I do this using CSH, Python or TCL itself?
Or is it not possible at all?

I tried going through some online resources and came across command named "events" but unfortunately it is not recognized by my TCL shell.

Comment: What happens if you press Tab on an empty line?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how restricted your Tcl-based shell is, might it be possible to simply try the command `lsort [info commands]`?

If the `info` command is available to you, `info commands` should produce a list of the commands your intepreter will recognize, and `lsort` simply puts the list into a sensible order.

Answer (score 0):

Tk provides `event generate` that lets you issue key press events (though you also need to remember the key release events to go with them). It won't deliver those to other applications; there might be an extension to do that, but it's a pretty rare requirement (just for GUI testing) and is likely a bad idea as **driving GUI applications by event injection is extremely fragile**. I'm guessing that's what you found mention of, and I really urge you to not even attempt that.

There are more options for driving terminal programs.

In the *simplest cases*, you can just use `open |theApplication r+` to get a bidirectional pipe to the application and read/write that, but that's *definitely* the simplest cases. In particular, you're likely to run into some really troubling buffering if you do that; it's very common for programs to fully buffer their output when it isn't going to a terminal (that's the default behaviour of a lot of programs).

It's likely easiest to use Expect (i.e., that's what I recommend), a Tcl extension, for driving any terminal application of complexity. Expect has been ported to other languages, though often it is just a subset of what the original Tcl extension does; it's things like being able to handle waiting for multiple different possible outputs that often gets omitted (as it is moderately complex to implement). There are numerous questions here whose answers show how to use Expect, and the manual page is also highly informative.